# AudioKit AKParametricEQ Filter type

Tags: ios, swift, audio, core-audio, audiokit

what kind of filter does AudioKit AKParametricEQ use to perform signal equalization?

http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKParametricEQ.html

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EQ used by AudioKit AKParametricEQ is a **biquad** according to Apple support:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/71251

Answer (score 0):

That particular class is a wrapper for Apple's own parametric EQ which has very little documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/kaudiounitsubtype_parametriceq

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you there is no documentation explaining what type of filter is implemented...